# K3 surface minus finite set

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds, k3-surfaces

Let $S$ be a complex K3 surface, and $P\subset S$ a finite set of points in $S$. It is known that 
$$
H^i(S,\mathbb{Z})\cong H^i(S\setminus P,\mathbb{Z})
$$
for $0\le i \le 2$. Then the Euler characteristic computation implies that $b_3(S\setminus P)=|P|$. I want to confirm that
$$
H^3(S\setminus P,\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{|P|}, 
$$
that is, there is no torsion.

Comment: What do you get from the Universal Coefficient Theorem?

Comment: I don't think $P$ yields any torsion in $H_2(S\setminus P,\mathbb{Z})$, so the UCT implies that $H^3(S\setminus P,\mathbb{Z})\cong Hom(H_3(S\setminus P,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$, but does this help?

Comment: I think it does, since $\mathrm{Hom}(T,\mathbb Z)$ vanishes if $T$ is torsion...

Comment: Sohrab, I think your Euler characteristic is off by one. Using Poincaré-Lefschetz duality will help give you a clean answer.